# Add Items in Sales Transaction table as single transaction

Tags: database

I've tables `Items` table as (Stock) and `Sales Transaction` so when I want to sale items from `Items` table `Sales Transaction` will generate `id`(auto increment) and will have all items added by user to sale.
But here is problem, how single transaction `id` can have multiple items in a row or how
`Sales Transaction` can generate same `id` for each row?

So even if I'll insert items to `Sales Transaction` for each item will have different `id` and so I'll not able to search reports correctly.
That will affect functionality.

I'm thinking to add all items in a single row like this:

[image]
So is there any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: The identity column is always going to be unique and should be for each row. If you need like ID's, you should make another column for that.

Comment: What I am talking about is adding a column to the existing table and not a foreign key to another table. It seems like it would stay a 1 to 1 relationship so no need to add another table. Add a column to the existing table. If there is already data in the table, you will have to either start over, or add data to the column for the existing items after the column is added. And yes, if you have a program behind the table, you will have to modify the code to account for the new column.

Comment: If customer name is the unique to the transaction, maybe this is all you need instead of adding another column?

Comment: Are you able to change the code in the program?

Comment: In that case, add the column. Have it as an INT and insert the value after getting the highest value in that column plus 1. When you add a group of data, assign the same number for all inserted rows in that column. Perhaps add a date column as well so you can search by date and is easier to find the data you are looking for.

Comment: Sure, i need more info on what you are using. Are you using SQL Server Management Studios, or something else?

Comment: Ok, I'll explain in answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a column, you need to alter the current table:

```
ALTER TABLE "Sales Transaction"
ADD COLUMN TransactionNumber INT NOT NULL
```

When you are inserting into this table you will need something like this:

```
DECLARE @TransNumber INT = (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(TransactionNumber) IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE MAX(TransactionNumber) + 1 END FROM "Sales Transaction")

INSERT INTO "Sales Transaction" ("Item Name", Qty., Price, "Cust. Name", Tax, Discount, Total, TransactionNumber) 
VALUES
('Pen',1,10,'John Smith',0,0,10,@TransNumber),
('Pencil',2,7,'John Smith',0,0,14.00,@TransNumber)
```

Since the TransactionNumber will be the same for both rows, you can search by that.

Comment: You can yes, but make sure when inserting that transaction number is already set in a variable that you can use for all group inserts. like i have in the answer. this is the part that you want is the most important change.

Comment: This ain't helpful it increase this `trans no.` for each row for batch insert.

Comment: Have it in a variable doesn't make a sense cause each time it will increase and also because of `max`.

Comment: I would need to see the structure of the database to know how I could help you differently. Why are you doing batch insert, i thought you were going to create a program behind the code. In the case of a program, my suggestion would work.